# how can i update a list with another List by using RxJava

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i hava a Student list and i need to update it by using a Update List .
Some thing like :

```
 List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Update> updates = new ArrayList<>();

    ListIterator<Student> studentListIterator = students.listIterator();
    ListIterator<Update> updateListIterator = updates.listIterator();

    while (updateListIterator.hasNext()) {
        Update update = updateListIterator.next();
        int id = update.getId();
        while (studentListIterator.hasNext()) {
            Student student = studentListIterator.next();
            int studentId = student.getId();
            if (studentId == id) {
                student.setScore(update.getDynamicScore() + 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Student.class:

```
 public class Student {
    int id;
    int score;
   }
```

Update class:

```
 public class Update {
    private int id;
    private int dynamicScore;
}
```

**how can i do that by using RxJava instead**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LIstIterator to modify list itself while iterating.

```
ListIterator<Student> iter = students.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   Student std = iter.next();
   // do your add/remove/edit operation here.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use operator merge in your observable to merge both list. 
Look this example

```
 /**
 * Here we merge two list and we sort the list for every new item added into.
 * Shall return
 *
 * [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
 */
@Test
public void testMergeLists() {
    Observable.merge(Observable.from(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 13, 11, 5)), Observable.from(Arrays.asList(10, 4, 12, 3, 14, 15)))
              .collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add)
              .doOnNext(Collections::sort)
              .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

If you want to learn more about RxJava with examples look here https://github.com/politrons/reactive